# Accordion link best practices

Tags: search, menu, filter

I'm working on improving my company's outdated filterable accordions on our intranet. I've been putting together some best practices, but have run into a bit of a roadblock. I can't seem to find anything defining best practices for accordion text links.

General rule for me personally is that if text is a link it would be best to make it the link color. When I review accordions across the web I find a great deal of variation. Some use text color links while others use the link color, but only for either the heading or the filterable links under the headings; rarely both.

Does anyone have any documentation highlighting this specifically for accordion/accordion filter menus?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the look and feel of the links, I strongly recommend to review these [Guidelines for Visualizing Links](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/guidelines-for-visualizing-links/)

What they suggest, from a usability perspective, is: "to maximize the perceived affordance of clickability, **color** and **underline** the link text. Users shouldn't have to guess or scrub the page to find out where they can click"

And this is particularly true from an inclusive angle; users with low vision or color blindness can understand that a particular text is clickable not only from the color but also from the underline.

The guidelines also suggest that "there are two main cases in which you can safely eliminate underlines: **navigation menus** and other **lists of links**"

To sum up:

- first of all aim for consistency with the other links of your system to rely on [recognition rather than recall](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/recognition-and-recall/#:%7E:text=Recognition%20refers%20to%20our%20ability,of%20related%20details%20from%20memory.)
- if you need to display standard links, use color and underline
- if inside the accordion you show a list of links or navigation items, use only color